# How to remove a subdivision of a cube

Tags: modeling

I want to know if there is a way to remove a smaller cube from a larger cube I subdivided. I removed the faces of the corner cube, but this reveals the inside. Is there a way to make the cube not hollow? So I could remove the outside faces and still not be able to see the inside? Thanks [image]

Comment: i think so you can slice the cube with a smaller cube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the seven verts of the corner. Select the lower right vertex last so it becomes the active (white) vertex.

[image: selection]

Extrude the selection with <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>. That way the newly created verts stay in their places. Set the pivot point to 'Active Object' and scale the selection to 0 on the Y axis <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. This will set all vertices to the y value of the active vertex, putting them in the back. Depending on how your object is oriented, you might need to pick a different axis.

[image: scaling]

Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and recalculate normals with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>

[image: repairing]

Comment: Could you explain the second step a bit more? I tried to scale the object to 0 on the Y axis but I believe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Whenever I try to scale everything on the Y axis to 0, it pulls all the other blocks to it creating slants, instead of creating flat edges like yours shows

Comment: @JoelBanks Sorry, I goofed up and left a step out. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Solidify Modifier.

-I added a default cube <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Cube.

-Then subdivided it three times <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide.

-Deleted the three faces in the top corner by selecting them and pressing <kbd>X</kbd> > Faces.

-Then added a Solidify Modifier and set the Thickness to .5 and checked the Even Thickness box.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it still looks hollow. Could you go into a but more detail about how you did this? Im very new to blender

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope it's clear.